# Why does my JTable over take my other JComponent

Tags: java, swing, layout, jcomponent, panels

I've been trying to sort this out for a while now, I have checked the docs (if you notice the table code is from there), and I just can't quite figure it out.  Am I using the wrong containers or do I need to dimension it?  If so, how?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Invest extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        demolayout frame = new demolayout();
        frame.setTitle("Financial Calculator");

        JPanel toppanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 2, 2));
        frame.add(toppanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        String[] columnNames = {"Entry", "Year", "Year", "Year", "Year"};

        Object[][] data = {{"Period Ending:", "2011", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Values in Millions of $", "12-31", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Revenue:", "46,542", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Revenue Other:", "-", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Total Revenue:", "46,542", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Cost of Revenue:", "18,216", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Gross Profit:", "28,326", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Selling Gen. Admin Expenses:", "12,111", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Research & Development:", "-", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Depreciation/Amortization:", "-", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Total Operating Expense:", "154", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Operating Income:", "35,810", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Interest Income (Exp.), Net NonOp:", "10,732", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Interest/Invest Inc. Non-Operating:", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Interest Inc. Net Non-Operating:", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Gain/Loss on Sale of Assets:", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Other, Net:", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Net Income Before Taxes:", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Income Tax - Total:", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Minority Interest:", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Equity In Affiliates:", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Accounting Change:", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Discontinued Operations:", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Extraordinary Items:", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Net Income:", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}};

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        toppanel.add(scrollPane);

        JPanel bottompanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        bottompanel.setBackground(new Color(150, 150, 150));

        JButton compute = new JButton("Compute Ratios");
        bottompanel.add(compute);
        frame.add(bottompanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Several. My scroll isn't there so I can't see some entries.  As well as , I have a compute ratios button that is in a panel to the south, and the Jtable Covers it.

Comment: I lied all my entries are there, I am going to update the code as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks good added to the frame's `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Also, don't create new objects if there's an existing primitive or factory method.

Addendum: *What do you mean factory method?*

Good question; `Integer. valueOf()` is a typical [*static factory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) method. As indicated in the API and discussed in Joshua Bloch's [*Item 1: Consider static factory methods instead of constructors*](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/208403883), the method caches frequently requested values.

[image: table]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Invest extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Financial Calculator");

        JPanel toppanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3, 2, 2));
        frame.add(toppanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        String[] columnNames = {"Entry", "Year", "Year", "Year", "Year"};

        Object[][] data = {{"Period Ending:", "2011", "Snowboarding", Integer.valueOf(5), false},
            {"Values in Millions of $", "12-31", "Rowing", Integer.valueOf(3), true},
            {"Revenue:", "46,542", "Knitting", Integer.valueOf(2), false},
            {"Revenue Other:", "-", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Total Revenue:", "46,542", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Cost of Revenue:", "18,216", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Gross Profit:", "28,326", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Selling Gen. Admin Expenses:", "12,111", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Research & Development:", "-", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Depreciation/Amortization:", "-", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Total Operating Expense:", "154", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Operating Income:", "35,810", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Interest Income (Exp.), Net NonOp:", "10,732", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Interest/Invest Inc. Non-Operating:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Interest Inc. Net Non-Operating:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Gain/Loss on Sale of Assets:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Other, Net:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Net Income Before Taxes:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Income Tax - Total:", "White", "Speed reading", Integer.valueOf(20), true},
            {"Minority Interest:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
            {"Equity In Affiliates:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
            {"Accounting Change:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
            {"Discontinued Operations:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
            {"Extraordinary Items:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false},
            {"Net Income:", "Brown", "Pool", Integer.valueOf(10), false}};

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel bottompanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        bottompanel.setBackground(new Color(150, 150, 150));

        JButton compute = new JButton("Compute Ratios");
        bottompanel.add(compute);
        frame.add(bottompanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: What do you mean factory method? Sorry, I'm just really getting into GUI